# Breaking changes in NEST 2.0 and ElasticSearch 2

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I had a WebAPI C# project using NEST 1.0 and ElasticSearch 1.0

Now I moved to NEST 2.0 and ElasticSearch 2.0 and it doesn't compile anymore

`ElasticType` has been deprecated for `ElasticsearchType`, that's fine

However, I have a bunch of properties for my POCOs:

```
[ElasticProperty(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
```

which I should rewrite using the new NEST 2.0 conventions

How can I do that?

Comment: Check this [breaking changes notes](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/2.0-breaking-changes/nest-breaking-changes.md#attribute-based-mapping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ElasticPropertyAttribute` has been replaced with more specific attributes in NEST 2.x such as `StringAttribute`, `DateAttribute`, etc.](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/2.0-breaking-changes/nest-breaking-changes.md#attribute-based-mapping) to reflect the properties available on each different field type mapping.

[**Documentation is available for NEST 2.x on the Elastic clients documentation site**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/index.html)